# Не получается загрузить Ubuntu в Virtual Box

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Не могу понять в чем проблема с Ubuntu [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.